Set Request Cookie in NextJS v14 Middleware
I want to set/update a cookie on the incoming request in the middleware file before the page or layout reads the cookie, but it seems to not be working. Maybe it's not possible..
I made a demo project you can clone from github:
https://github.com/TJBlackman/nextjs-middleware-set-cookies-test
// middleware.ts
import type { NextRequest } from "next/server";

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  console.log(`running middleware....`, request.method, request.url);
  request.cookies.set("x-middleware-test", "some test value?!"); // <- this line should set a cookie that can be read by layout/page??
}

// layout.tsx
import { cookies } from "next/headers";

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  const cookieStore = cookies();
  const testCookie = cookieStore.get("x-middleware-test");

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <h1>Layout cookie: {testCookie?.value || "Not Found"}</h1>
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

// page.tsx
import { cookies } from "next/headers";

export default function Home() {
  const cookieStore = cookies();
  const testCookie = cookieStore.get("x-middleware-test");
  return (
    <main>
      <h2>Page cookie: {testCookie?.value || "Not Found"}</h2>
    </main>
  );
}


This worked for me in NextJS v14.2.4:
export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  request.cookies.set("x-middleware-test", "some test value?!");

  return NextResponse.next({
    request, // <- overwrite the request object!! yay! :D
  });
}

I updated the example repo to demonstrate this working. The NextJS docs are kinda obscure imo...
Edit: Just some more info, which is that you have to set request cookies BEFORE you pass the request object to the NextResponse.next() method. As an example, this will NOT work...
// example of what does NOT work!!
export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const response = NextResponse.next({
    request, // set this object as it is NOW, not including future changes
  });

  request.cookies.set("x-middleware-test", "some test value?!");

  return response; // won't include set-cookie changes :(
}


NextRequest is based on the Web Request API spec (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request) where request sub-objects are readonly  and its usually considered anti-pattern to rewrite but if its a simple thing and you want all request objects have that cookie then this maybe OK until Next makes it readonly.

If NextJS implemented actual middleware (like express, fastify, sveltekit, etc), then it would be fine, but they implement middleware as a completely isolated function (dumb). The use case is when a request has a valid RefreshToken, and I want to use that to get/set a new valid access token for the remainder of the lifetime of the request.

The issue is you should use NextResponse - NextRequest is read only and is the incoming request, Response is what is sent onward.
So
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import type { NextRequest } from "next/server";

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  console.log(`running middleware....`, request.method, request.url);

  const response = NextResponse.next();
  response.cookies.set("x-middleware-test", "some test value?!");

  return response;
}

Getting rid of async is a good idea unless you need to await something in the middleware.
Client Side handling
 useEffect(() => {
    if (!Cookies.get('x-middleware-test')) {
      Cookies.set('x-middleware-test', 'some test value?!');
    }

If cookie values need to be secure use RSC instead
More reading - https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware#using-cookies

This does not work. In the initial page render, the cookie is still not read. This does set a cookie on the response to the client (a browser), which saves the cookies and includes it on future page loads, but on the very first page load, it is still not available.

You are right but handled through a client-side effect
if (!Cookies.get('x-middleware-test')) {
Cookies.set('x-middleware-test', 'some test value?!');
}
If the cookie value is not to be disclosed to the client use RSC https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/server-components
